# GWT: How to achieve an accordion effect in a Cell List?

Tags: css, gwt, accordion, rpc, celllist

I have a RPC-generated list of widgets with headers and bodies. I would like to display them vertically, with only the headers showing. When the user clicks a header, the corresponding body slides down into view, and any other open bodies slide out of view.

The accordion effect can be achieved with a StackPanel. However, I also want the ease of paging and accessing remote data afforded by CellList and AsyncDataProvider. It [looks like](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6328) the two will be available together in GWT 2.5, which unfortunately is not out yet.

Another idea I had was to just use a CellList, and use relative positioning on each cell to get the accordion effect. The logic is simple enough to implement, but grabbing the cells from the cell list and messing with their `style` attribute seems like a dirty hack.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Followup**: (I'm not sure if this should be a separate question.) The CellList's structure looks something like this:

```
<div __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true" class="GJOQRHCBPB GJOQRHCBMK">  

<div onclick="" __idx="0" class="GJOQRHCBLB" style="outline:none;" tabindex="0">
  <!-- my cell html -->
</div>
<div onclick="" __idx="1" class="GJOQRHCBLB" style="outline:none;" tabindex="1"> <!-- ... -->
<div onclick="" __idx="2" class="GJOQRHCBLB" style="outline:none;" tabindex="2"> <!-- ... -->
<!-- ... -->
</div></div>
```

Styling my cell is easy enough, and it displays correctly on the page. However, my styling of the cell doesn't influence the parent divs (with `__idx`), and they still stretch out the entire original length. This means that if you click beneath where the cell list "should be", selection events will be fired. This could be fixed if I could just access and style the `__idx` divs directly, but I'm afraid that's a horribly dirty hack. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What GWT 2.5 will add is a way to build several rows for a single item **in a `CellTable`** (or `DataGrid`); it won't change anything for `CellList`s. Also, you'll still be in charge of handling the events to expand/collapse the rows, possibly animating them, and *at most one expanded row* won't come for free either.

All in all, it won't change anything for your use-case.

You need to bake this expand/collapse behavior in your cell's rendering/event handling. As for collapsing other rows, you'll have to process the DOM starting from the list level (i.e. find all collapsible elements and make sure they're collapsed, then expand the row that needs it).
Alternatively, you could use, say, a `NoSelectionModel` or `SingleSelectionModel` and simply render the selected/last-selected item as expanded, and others collapsed (triggering redraw from the `SelectionHandler` if needed). You'd probably lose animations though.

Comment: Will the `SelectionHandler` provide me with access to the cells themselves?

Comment: No, but you can give the `SelectionModel` to the cells so they can have access to the selected state of the item they're rendering. I don't remember how it goes, but in case selection change doesn't automatically triggers a redraw, you can call `redraw()` on the `CellList` to force re-rendering.

Comment: Good to know. That worked, but now I'm having another issue. (OP updated.)

Comment: Styling the cells is as easy as providing your own `CellList.Resources` and `CellList.Style`.

Comment: That will apply a style to all the cells, but what I want to do is apply a different style rule to each one (to get the accordion effect).